# Getting through my "complex" form

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm currently working on a website that uses the MVC architecture. I'm fairly new to all this stuff and I'm wondering what goes where very often.  I have four question related to the same issue. thanks for giving me 5 minutes!

I've come to a problem where I have a "model" (i think) that is called Household. The household is made has an adress, a phone number and members. Phone number and adress are in table 'family' and members are in table 'member' (with a foreing key for family). 
**Question1: Are Household, family and member "models" in the MVC sense?**

I also have another "model" which is "course". Members of family can take "courses". Courses are defined by "level" and have a time identifier. **Question 2 : is "course" a model in the MVC sense?**

Members can take courses and i want to be able to track all the courses they have taken in the past. This link is not a model in the MVC sense. My "member" model would have a list of class taken. I would then need an extra table linking member and course. **Question 3: How do i make this possible in an MVC (a controller? View? Helper? a DAL only?)**

Here is my problem: for the launch of the website, i want household to be created by first entering a course ID. There would be a form where the used first enters a courseid. By pressing submit, the user will then be redirected to a form where he can enters the household detail and the name of the member that have taken the course linked to 
the id entered in the previous form. That form would have an extra data which is the detail of the entered course id. **Question 4: What controller / view / model should i use to make this happen?**

My actual solution, which i don't like, is having a get action that is different wether there is an id entered or not. the problem is that if there is an ID entered, it would be a course id from the first form (which is not the right way to do it...). I would prefer to have my get action with id to return a household...not a form to generate a new household...

Thanks for answering my question. if you have any usefull reference for helping me understanding the mvc (i'm learning by myself by trials and errorsss...) - don't hesitate to share.

have a great night!

Answer (score 0):

Think of models as a representation of any information you store in a database. More accurately, it's the "knowledge" of your application. Anything intended to represent something in the real-world, for which you can have one or more record in a database.

Views are simply put, any distinct visual representation of how those objects are associated. This would be for example the fact that the UI you're seeing on this question is a "view" for the models that are the question/answers/users on StackOverflow.

A controller is just code that figures out which view a user is trying to access at a given time, which can often provide models to the views. The view will then take the models it was given and display any information it needs to display.

As for your practical questions, it sounds like you just need to learn more about the MVC architecture in general. Your specific questions are a lot like the "Can someone write this for me or tell me how to write it?" questions that are frowned upon here on StackOverflow. Show some initiative and prove that you've tried something, and that you're hung up on something you've tried, and you're much more likely to get an answer to those. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i was more looking for a yes/no for question 1 and 2. as for question 3-4 i was looking for a philosophical discussion. i understand that people in here are looking to get stuff done ;) i'll try to find a IT friend to discuss this over a beer

Comment: And that's your problem. instead, you should be looking for an understanding of what models/views _are_, so that you can answer your own question there. The simple answers for 1 and 2 are yes, and yes.

Comment: i definitively have to learn the MVC architecture in general. i can't agree more. Any good reference, online class you would recommand?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/2 is a good place to start.

Comment: Excellent. Very much appreciated. and by asking the question i realised there a bunch of relevant link on the right. have a great night.

Comment: @V13Axel master jeffrey way, will lead him to the right way